# Desigining a new Joomla component

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, components

I've very less experience in Joomla. I'm going to create a joomla component. I've heard about the MVC structure in component development. What is the best method to follow? 1)Using  simple component development or 2) using MVC
Is there any problems if I uses the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking MVC makes it easier for you to later expand the component. You might not think now that it will be needed but it is a common situation in IT that your client suddenly has new requirements. With MVC introducing those new requirements is much easier thanks to the separation of the code and design.

Another advantage to doing it in MVC is that it will be a great chance for you to learn. Knowledge and experience with the MVC pattern is a huge advantage for any web developer.

If you find yourself struggling at some point, I will recommend [Mastering Joomla](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849510520) which is a great reference for Joomla developers.

Answer (score 1):

Mastering Joomla is a great book for learning the MVC. It's also worth downloading a hello world example MVC component - something like http://www.mightyextensions.com/knowledge-base/joomla-tutorials/item/developer-center/44-component-mvc-ajax/758-joomla-hello-world-mvc-component-tutorial but there are lots around to help.

Answer (score 0):

here is reference link that describe each & everything in very simple way

[Joomla Component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1)
[Another link with example](http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components)
ask me if u have any doubts, i have just learnd to develope component, please share your knowledge also.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this [link joomla-component-creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/index.php).

It is useful to understand how to create a joomla component.

There you can generate a joomla component. you can get help there by clicking more info.

Hope helpful.